# How to deserialize an array of JSON objects into a HashMap<key, struct> where key is one of the fields

Tags: rust, serde

I am struggling to instruct `serde` to deserialize a JSON array of objects into a HashMap whose key is found from one of the fields of the object and value is a struct built out of the remaining keys of the object.  Here's a simplified example:

```json
[
  {"name" : "John", "age" : 11, "registry" : true},
  {"name" : "Clyde", "age" : 14, "registry" : false},
  {"name" : "Bob", "age" : 12, "registry" : true}
]
```

Now I need to deserialize the whole JSON into `AllPeople` with each object getting deserialized into `Person`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct AllPeople(HashMap<String, Person>);

struct Person {
    age: u32,
    registry: bool,
}
```

I'd like for the value associated with the `"name"` field of the JSON object to serve as the key for the `AllPeople` map.

1. Is there a way to achieve this using any macros provided by `serde`?
2. If not, how do I modify the behavior of deserialize to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [specifying](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) a custom deserialization function in your wrapper via `#[serde(deserialize_with = "mappify")]`:

```
use serde::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    age: u32,
    registry: bool,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct JsonPerson {
    age: u32,
    registry: bool,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct AllPeople(#[serde(deserialize_with = "mappify")] HashMap<String, Person>);

fn mappify<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<HashMap<String, Person>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    use serde::de::*;
    struct ItemsVisitor;
    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for ItemsVisitor {
        type Value = HashMap<String, Person>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("a sequence of items")
        }

        fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut seq: V) -> Result<HashMap<String, Person>, V::Error>
        where
            V: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut map = HashMap::with_capacity(seq.size_hint().unwrap_or(0));

            while let Some(item) = seq.next_element::<JsonPerson>()? {
                let JsonPerson {
                    age,
                    registry,
                    name,
                } = item;
                match map.entry(name) {
                    std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Occupied(entry) => {
                        return Err(serde::de::Error::custom(format!(
                            "Duplicate entry {}",
                            entry.key()
                        )))
                    }
                    std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                        entry.insert(Person { age, registry })
                    }
                };
            }
            Ok(map)
        }
    }

    de.deserialize_seq(ItemsVisitor)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bde0753720bdb0c95522bed6c8221d9)

Note that as mentioned in the issue linked by @ChayimFriedman, the performance benefits are questionable and probably not worth the wordiness. Possibly, the Vec is even faster, because it doesn't need to do the complicated resizing of a hashmap during adding.

Personally, I'd probably go with

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "Vec<JsonPerson>")]
struct AllPeople(HashMap<String, Person>);

impl TryFrom<Vec<JsonPerson>> for AllPeople {
    type Error = String;

    fn try_from(value: Vec<JsonPerson>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        // This could be value.into_iter().map(…).collect(), but I care about duplicates.
        let mut map = HashMap::with_capacity(value.len());
        for item in value {
            let JsonPerson {
                age,
                registry,
                name,
            } = item;
            match map.entry(name) {
                std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Occupied(entry) => {
                    return Err(format!("Duplicate entry {}", entry.key()))
                }
                std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                    entry.insert(Person { age, registry })
                }
            };
        }
        Ok(AllPeople(map))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79f2a4e3378122fb4d9d1cc07f35a72e)

---

Side note: I feel like `serde_with::serde_as` should be able to do that with something like

```rust
struct AllPeople(#[serde_as(as = "Seq<JsonPerson>")] HashMap<String, Person>);
```

but I've only been able to get it to produce a `Vec<(String, Person)>`. If somebody can demonstrate `serde_as`, that'd be neat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that its possible to serialize the data directly into the hashtable, but you should be able to do something like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct JsonPerson {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
    registry: bool,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    age: u32,
    registry: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let people: Vec<JsonPerson> = serde_json::from_str("<your json string>").unwrap();
    let mut all_people: HashMap<String, Person> = HashMap::new();
    for person in people {
        let key = person.name; 
        let value = Person { age: person.age, registry: person.registry };
        all_people.insert(key, value);
    }
    println!("{:#?}", all_people);
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution: so the idea is to do a second pass to restructure the data into the desired form.  Thanks!  Ok, I'll wait for others to see if there is something that doesn't require that extra pass.

Comment: @QuantumDot As per [issue #936](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/936) there doesn't appear to be a better way, but you can bake the transformation into the deserialization.